# Troubleshooting Magento 1.9.2.4 with PHP 7

Tags: php-7, troubleshooting

I've been doing some research and decided to go ahead with an upgrade to PHP v7. Initially my front-end and back-end were non responsive, just a blank white page.

Running the latest version of Magento 1.9.2.4.

I came across the inchoo compatibility module: http://inchoo.net/magento/its-alive/

This resolved my front-end issues, but I cannot login to my admin panel. The header loads but that is it. There are no errors in any of the logs.

I did a search in my `local` and `community` directories to check for incompatible code that might be responsible:

```
grep -rnPe .'->\$.+\[.+\]\(.*\)'
```

The only results were from the `core` which are resolved by the Inchoo PHP 7 module.

Others seem to have had the exact same problem:

> from magento 1.9.2.2, uploaded Seven to the server, then change to PHP 7.0 and my side goes blank.
>   No errors, just nothing on the screen.

I'm sure this is a common issue and would like to get this documented since I could not find any solution to resolve this.

With no errors in the logs I am at a loss on how to troubleshoot the back-end issues.

Can someone provide a solution or guide me into how to resolve this?

For the close happy people in this section of SE:

**I'm not asking if it is compatible, I'm asking how to make it work given the troubleshooting I've already done**

Comment: I suggest checking that PHP error logging is enabled, might be that it is disabled on the box. When I was testing and had a similar problem it was a fatal error in a script that was causing it so found that out via the Nginx/Apache error logs.

Comment: @JohnCuthbert I did check the logs but I'll double check to see if something was disabled, thank you!

Comment: @JohnCuthbert I had it turned off. I finally had some time to clone my server and attempt the upgrade to php7. Between this suggestion and the answer this solved my problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Magento 1.9 with the Inchoo patch and without additional extensions is compatible with PHP 7, it's a problem with either a third party extension or custom code and I can only give you hints where to look:

> The header loads but that is it

This usually means, PHP has crashed with a Fatal Error during template rendering. With developer mode turned on you should see the error message if you use "View Source" in your browser. If not, check the **PHP error logs** (not Magento error logs!)

> I did a search in my local and community directories to check for incompatible code that might be responsible:
>
> ```
>  grep -rnPe .'->\$.+\[.+\]\(.*\)'
> ```

The regex you used addresses only one particular compatibility issue. To find more potential issues, there are static analysis tools like https://github.com/sstalle/php7cc - use them instead.

Comment: Much appreciated!, I will check this and come back